# Laravel formatting a date in_array

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Having trouble formatting the date in a Laravel application. It's currently showing the date like so:

Monday, **15:00:00**

I would like the 15:00:00 to be in the following format:

**3:00pm** (g:ia)

I tried to wrap using Carbon using: \Carbon\Carbon::parse(...)->format('g:ia') but returned errors.

```
@foreach($days[$index] as $dateIndex => $day)
   @if($day == 'Monday')
      Monday, {{ in_array($dates[$index][$dateIndex], $date[$index]) ? 'Not Available' : $club->monday }}
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Thanks.

Comment: What variable is the date stored in? Can you do a `DD` on it so we can see what type of variable is it (string, carbon instance, etc)

Comment: @atymic I believe it's $date[$index]

Comment: @tebrown where `$club->monday` came from?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys.

I need to wrap `$club->monday` with carbon format.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($club->monday)->format('g:ia')
```